# Циклы и последовательность выполнения методов

Tags: java, android, циклы, таймер

Здравствуйте!

Есть задача написать таймер Табата (интервальный таймер). Методы отсчета отдельно работают, а вот вместе не хотят - при нажатии на кнопку "Start" приложение просто зависает. Может где ошибка, подскажите. Вот код:

```
public class ActivityTimer extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView mTextWork;
private TextView mTextRest;
private TextView mTextRound;
private NumberPicker pickerSecWork;
private NumberPicker pickerSecRest;
private NumberPicker pickerRound;
int n;
long secWork;
long secRest;
int numberRound;
boolean mIsRunning = false;
int mCurrentPeriod = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);

    mTextWork = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewWork);
    mTextRest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRest);
    mTextRound = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRound);
    pickerSecWork = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.pickerWO);
    pickerSecRest = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.pickerR);
    pickerRound = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.pickerRound);
    pickerSecWork.setMinValue(0);
    pickerSecWork.setMaxValue(59);
    pickerSecRest.setMinValue(0);
    pickerSecRest.setMaxValue(59);
    pickerRound.setMinValue(0);
    pickerRound.setMaxValue(8);
    pickerSecWork.setOnValueChangedListener(onValueChangedWork);
    pickerSecRest.setOnValueChangedListener(onValueChangedRest);
}

// Реализация таймеров

public void TimerWorkOut() {
    new CountDownTimer(secWork, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTextWork.setText(" " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            mTextWork.setText("Rest!");
        }
    }.start();
}

public void TimerRest() {
    new CountDownTimer(secRest, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTextRest.setText(" " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            mTextRest.setText("Just do it!");
        }
    }.start();
}

// Кнопки

public void ClickStart(View view) {
    secWork = pickerSecWork.getValue() * 1000;
    secRest = pickerSecRest.getValue() * 1000;
    numberRound = pickerRound.getValue();
    do {
        TimerWorkOut();
        if (secWork == 0) {
            TimerRest();
        }
    } while (n <= numberRound);
}

public void ClickCancel(View v) {

}

// слушатели NumberPicker, и передача данных в TextWiew

NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener onValueChangedWork = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        if (!mIsRunning) {
            mTextWork.setText(intToTime(newVal));
            mCurrentPeriod = newVal;
        }
    }
};

NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener onValueChangedRest = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        if (!mIsRunning) {
            mTextRest.setText(intToTime(newVal));
            mCurrentPeriod = newVal;
        }
    }
};

// методы для чтения данных с NumberPicker

private String intToTime(int i) {
    return (new SimpleDateFormat("ss")).format(new Date(i * 1000));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while (n <= numberRound);` - n не изменяется, бесконечный цикл получается, вот и зависает.

Comment: Изменил код кнопки:

 public void ClickStart(View view) {
        secWork = pickerSecWork.getValue() * 1000;
        secRest = pickerSecRest.getValue() * 1000;
        numberRound = pickerRound.getValue();
        do {
            TimerWorkOut();
            if (secWork == 0) {
                TimerRest();
            }
            n++;
            mTextRound.setText(" " + n);
        } while (n <= numberRound);
    }

Но почему-то срабатывает только таймер Work, а счетчик раундов просто делает +1 за каждое нажатие "Старт". Не подскажите как переработать цикл?

Comment: Если нужно отслеживать окончание первого таймера, то почему бы не запусать второй (TimerRest) в onFinish() у TimerWorkOut. Они не синхронны и в одном цикле  не удастся дождаться окончания.

Comment: Работает!
Таймеры работают последовательно. Спасибо. Буду теперь дорабатывать цикл повторения по раундам.